# Inference on Multiple Label Sentiment analysis using pytorch_lightning

Tags: nlp, sentiment-analysis, inference, pytorch-lightning

I have trained an LSTM model for sentiment analysis using pytorch_lightning but I've been having difficulties incorporating the inference.
This is my model:

```
class LSTM(pl.LightningModule):
 def __init__(self,n_vocab,n_embed, 
 n_hidden,n_output,n_layers,learning_rate,embedding_matrix=None):
  super().__init__()
  self.n_vocab = n_vocab
  self.n_layer = n_layers
  self.n_hidden = n_hidden
  self.embedding = nn.Embedding(n_vocab, n_embed, padding_idx = 0)
  if embedding_matrix is not None:
   self.embedding.weight = nn.Parameter(torch.tensor(embedding_matrix, dtype=torch.float32))
   self.embedding.weight.requires_grad = False
  self.lstm = nn.LSTM(n_embed, n_hidden, n_layers, batch_first = True, bidirectional = True)
  self.fc = nn.Linear(2 * n_hidden, n_output)
  self.dropout = nn.Dropout(0.2)
  self.sigmoid = nn.Sigmoid()
  self.batch_size = batch_size
  self.learning_rate = learning_rate
 
 def forward(self,input_words):
  embedded_words = self.embedding(input_words)
  lstm_out, _ = self.lstm(embedded_words)
  lstm_out_f=lstm_out[:,-1  , :300 ]
  lstm_out_b=lstm_out[:, 0 , 300: ]
  lstm_out_final = torch.cat([lstm_out_f,lstm_out_b], dim=-1)
  lstm_out_final = self.dropout(lstm_out_final)
  fc_out = self.fc(lstm_out_final)
  return fc_out

 def configure_optimizers(self):
  optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(self.parameters(), lr = self.learning_rate)
  return optimizer

 def training_step(self, batch, batch_nb):
    x , y= batch
    y_hat = self(x)
    loss = F.cross_entropy(y_hat, y)
    self.log("train_loss", loss, on_step=True, on_epoch=True, prog_bar=True, logger=True)
    return loss

 def validation_step(self, batch, batch_nb):
    x, y = batch
    y_hat = self(x)
    loss = F.cross_entropy(y_hat, y).to(device = 'cuda')
    f1 = torchmetrics.F1(num_classes=5).to(device = 'cuda')
    f1_score = f1(y_hat, y)
    accuracy = Accuracy().to(device = 'cuda')
    accur = accuracy(y_hat, y)
    self.log("val_loss", loss)
    self.log("f1_score", f1_score)
    self.log("accuracy", accur)

  def test_step(self, batch, batch_idx):
    x, y = batch
    logits = self(x)
    print(logits)
    logitsies = softmax(logits)
    choice = argmax(logitsies)
    loss = F.nll_loss(logits, y)
    self.log("test_loss", loss)
    return choice

  def predict_step(self, batch, batch_idx, dataloader_idx):
    x, y = batch
    x = x.view(x.size(0), -1)
    y_hat = self(x)
    logitsies = softmax(logits)
    choice = argmax(logitsies)
    loss = F.nll_loss(logits, y)
    self.log("predict_loss", loss)
    return choice
```

I called the model as such:

```
model = LSTM(
n_vocab=size_of_emb_matrix,
n_embed=embed_vector_len,
n_hidden=150,
n_output=5,
n_layers=1,
learning_rate=1e-4,
embedding_matrix=embedding_matrix    
)
```

Now I am trying to write a function that would allow me to do inference. I have managed to succesfuly tokenize the input sentence and encode it through an already pre-defined functions, yet I have been getting several errors no matter what I try. I have found myself stuck and don't know how to continue. This is my function so far.

```
def get_sentiment(text):
 x = encode_sentence(text,vocab2index)
 x_bar = x[0]
 y_hat = torch.tensor(x_bar)
 trainer.predict(model,y_hat)
```

The encode_sentence function is as follows:

```
def encode_sentence(text, vocab2index, N=70):
 tokenized = tokenize(text)
 encoded = np.zeros(N, dtype=int)
 enc1 = np.array([vocab2index.get(word, vocab2index["UNK"]) for word in tokenized])
 length = min(N, len(enc1))
 encoded[:length] = enc1[:length]
 return encoded, length
```

As I call the get_sentiment function, I am using the trainer.predict function which allows me to predict, hence doing inference.
But I have been getting the following Issue:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call 
last)
<ipython-input-195-825c536cbbb2> in <module>()
----> 1 get_sentiment("love that dress")

13 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist- 
packages/pytorch_lightning/loops/epoch/prediction_epoch_loop.py in 
_store_batch_indices(self, dataloader_idx)
162     def _store_batch_indices(self, dataloader_idx: int) -> None:
163         """Stores the batch indices if the predictions should be 
stored"""
--> 164         batch_sampler = 
self.trainer.predict_dataloaders[dataloader_idx].batch_sampler
165         if isinstance(batch_sampler, IndexBatchSamplerWrapper):
166             self.current_batch_indices = batch_sampler.batch_indices

AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'batch_sampler'
```

Comment: ".. getting several errors .. " - please post these errors and clarify the question

Comment: AttributeError: 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.EagerTensor' object has no attribute 'batch_sampler'.
This is the error I am getting when I run this function:
def get_sentiment(text):
  x = encode_sentence(text,vocab2index)
  x_bar = x[0]
  print(x_bar)
  x_hat = tf. convert_to_tensor(x_bar)
  trainer.predict(model,x_hat)

Comment: Sorry I am bit confused. What part of this is related to Tensorflow? Kindly edit your question and post the *full error traceback*.

Comment: Edited the necesssary, and added the error.